# vmc tunnel cant select a client, says Please disambiguate: mysqldump or mysql?

Tags: cloud-foundry

i am trying to connect to mysql service via vmc tunnel. Everythings is ok until i have to choose a service.

Log:

Starting tunnel to mysql-7624 on port 10000.
1: none
2: mysqldump
3: mysql
Which client would you like to start?: mysql
Please disambiguate: mysqldump or mysql?
Which client would you like to start?: mysql
Please disambiguate: mysqldump or mysql?

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

please just enter the number of the client you wish to start as apposed to the name of the client, i.e 2 for mysqldump or 3 for mysql.